# FileSystemWatcher C# service name

Tags: c#, windows, alert, filesystemwatcher

I know how to use FileSystemWatcher Class but i want to know how to get the user, application or the service that have modify the specific file?

Answer (score 0):

FileSystemWatcher can't help you in this case.

To get such information, you can set appropriate audit rules for filesystem objects (for instance, using classes from System.Security.AccessControl namespace) with consequent reading of Windows Audit Log.

As an altenative, you can write a kernel driver, or use some external utility like ProcessMonitor by Sysinternals, if you need to get such information episodically or depending on other project specifics.

In any case it could require significant resources.